# How can I access a list that is created in a static object that is part of another class?

Tags: c#

What I would like to do is to have a list that is in an object `counts` that is defined in the `App` class as a static when my application starts:

Here's the object:

```
public class Counts
{
    public Counts()
    {
       public static List<CntQty> CardClicks2m;
    }
}
```

In my application I declare this

am using the following code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static Counts counts = new Counts();

    public App()
    {
    }
}
```

Now I try to use load some data into the list but it gives me the error below. Note that this function is in another class.

```
public void GetClickHistory()
{
   App.counts.CardClicks2m = db2.Query<CntQty>(sql);
```

The last line of the code is giving me an error saying

> counts.CardClicks2m cannot be accessed with an instance reference;
>   qualify it with a type name instead.

I have tried a few different ways to make this work. One by removing the static and creating the object in the app constructor. This also didn't seem to work so I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction or at least suggest something.

Comment: "if someone could say why" Usually there´s a reason that does exactly this, something like "the question was closed, because..." and afterwards a list of members that voted to do so. But I can´t see any closed question within your list of questions. Was it deleted afterwards?

Comment: it always says why.. whats your question link - but back to this one

Comment: The reason is that `CardClicks2m` is static, `counts` is an instance, the compiler doesn't allow you to access a static member through an instance reference. Instead of `App.counts.CardClicks2m` simply do `Counts.CardClicks2m`. In any case, please post an [mcve] as the code in your question simply doesn't compile. You cannot have a static local variable (as in the Counts constructor) so clearly this is not your real code.

Comment: Sorry I don't recall what the reason for closing was but it was something like could not reproduce or a typo.  But I checked a few times and there was no typo and I can always reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because you are trying to access to a static member from a instance object

```
public void GetClickHistory()
{
   App.counts.CardClicks2m = db2.Query<CntQty>(sql);
```

**EDITED after comments**:
Try this (accessing the static member from the class):

```
public void GetClickHistory()
{
   Counts.CardClicks2m = db2.Query<CntQty>(sql);
```

As CardClicks2m is declared static, it must be accessed from the class scope. If Counts class doen't have any other code, you can declare

```
public static class Counts
```

And there is not neccesary to create an instance of counts

```
public static Counts counts = new Counts(); //this is not neccesary
```

Comment: When I do this it tells me that App does not contain a definition for Counts.

Answer (score 1):

i guess scope of variable is not right , you need to do like this

```
public class Counts
{
    public static List<CntQty> CardClicks2m;
    public Counts()
    {       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed to your suggestion but I still get the same error.  Thanks for taking the time to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self explanatory, you cannot access a static property using an instance variable. all you need to do is use the typename. So this:

```
App.Counts.CardClicks2m
```

Becomes this:

```
Counts.CardClicks2m
```

You may need to specify the full namespace of the `Counts` class:

```
Some.Namespace.Counts.CardClicks2m
```

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks very much.  I have added a USING and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

As your `CardClicks2m`-member is static there´s no need to have any instance of your `Counts`- or aven your `App`-class. The member exists once per appdomain however. Having said this in order to access `CardClicks2m` you don´t have to create an instance of your `Counts`-class within `App`.

Use this instead:

```
class MyClass
{
    void DoSometjing()
    {
        Counts.CardClicks2m = db2.Query<CntQty>(sql).ToList();
    }
}
```

Be aware to that `Query` will surely not return a `List<CntQty>`, but an `IQueryable<CntQty>`, that´s why you should call `ToList` afterwards.

Furthermore you can´t declare a member within a method or constructor. Thus declare it within the class´-body instead of the constructor:

```
public class Counts
{
    public static List<CntQty> CardClicks2m;
    public Counts() { /* any further initialzation */ }   }
}
```

Comment: When I do this it tells me that Counts does not exist in the current context.